# What is updateing SPSite.LastContentModifiedDate property

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I just pulled the SPSite.LastContentModifiedDate property on every site in my farm and noticed that all 315 sites were updated between the time of 5/7/2013 12:01:21 AM and 5/7/2013 1:20:00 AM.

Considering this is unlikely at that hour I am looking for explanations on why that data is being updated.

I also need a more reliable property that indicates the last time something was updated by a user.'

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of default timer jobs in the farm is being updated frequently.

Ref:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff808317(v=office.14).aspx

You can use the LastItemModifiedDate property of the Web object.

Answer (score 0):

The value of this property is taken from the AllSites table in the content database where SPSite is resided. There are two columns AllSites.LastContentChange and AllSites.LastSecurityChange.

The AllSites.LastContentChange column is updated by stored procedure proc_QMChangeSiteDiskUsedAndContentTimestamp.

In order the stored procedure is used by other procedures that updates site  related data. below you can find the stored procedures that calls proc_QMChangeSiteDiskUsedAndContentTimestamp. this is screenshot of such procedures:
[image]

and these stored procedures could be used by the timer jobs listed above. 
proc_SetWebMetainfo - called when you updates SPWeb.AllProperties collection
proc_UpdateDiskUsed - called every time when you provision content type or field to the site.

Answer (score 0):

This could have been a bug in SharePoint 2013, acknowledged by Microsoft, and corrected (in some cases) according to the following uservoice entry:

**https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/15112005-modified-dates-in-site-contents-should-reflect-con**